What were the details of Brahmagupta's theory of gravitation?
When talking of our evolving idea of Gravitation we usually talk about Aristotle's theory of falling things, Newton's universal gravitation and Einstein's general relativity. However, I want to ask of Brahmagupta's theory that developed independently of this scientific tradition.
He called it Gurutvaakarshanam, which literally translates to "Attraction of Massive Bodies". This made me interested, as it implied that he was somewhat close to Newton's theory. But when I read a quotation about it on his Wikipedia page, it seemed very similar to Aristotle's theory. So, if Brahmagupta thought of gravitation as things going down to Earth, then why did he did he call it Attraction of Massive Bodies? Can someone provide Brahmagupta's theory in detail?

Brahmagupta's name came into prominence when the Rajasthan
education minister credited him in 2018 in a public speech with discovering the law of gravity before Newton. But the claim is greatly exaggerated given the record, even if the "law" is interpreted purely qualitatively.
A detailed discussion of Indian views on gravity can be found in Roy, Al-Biruni And Hindu Speculations on Gravitation. The gurutvaakarshanam in Brahmagupta refers merely to the Earth attracting massive bodies. The quote is:

"Scholars have declared that the globe of the earth is in the midst of
heaven and that the North pole is the home of the devas, as well the South pole
'below' is the home of their opponents. But this 'below' is without any meaning.
Disregarding this we say that the earth on all sides is the same; all people
on earth stand upright and all heavy things fall down to the earth by a law
of nature, for it is the nature of the earth to attract and to keep things, as
it is the nature of water to flow, that of the fire to burn and that of the
wind to set in motion. If a thing wants to go beyond the earth let it try.
The earth is the only low thing; and seeds always return to it in whatever
direction you may throw them away; and never rise upwards from the earth"."

The idea of attractive force is a step from Aristotle's natural motion, but still very far from universal gravity.
Even generally, if Indian speculations did extend beyond terrestrial attraction it was only in a very vague and obscure form concerning the spherical shape of the cosmos:

"That terrestrial attraction loomed large in Hindu astronomical speculations hardly requires much elaboration. What, however, is not so very certain is whether or to what extent, if at all, the ancient Indian astronomer was
aware of the role of cosmic gravitation in the ordering of planetary movements... Less elusive in this context would appear to be some of the expressions occurring in a fragmentary text of Aryabhata, which do seem to imply on his part some awareness of the idea of universal gravitation, albeit in a very rudimentary and embryonic form. The text reads: 'Surrounded by the vault of the celestial dome and girdled by the equator, exists the terrestrial globe,
entirely round, a compound of earth, water, fire and air, held in grip in space'... His text is fragmentarv and we do not know what precise shape his thinking on the subject ultimately took. It would appear, however, that he did think in terms of some kind of universal force which held the earth firmly in space.


Much of what we know of ancient Indian astronomical thinking is derived from what al-Biruni has to say on this subject in his monumental
work on India... He was aware that according to the Indian view, "everything heavy gravitates towards the earth". It also appears that he had gathered that the applicability
of this so called law of gravitation, according to the Indian way of thinking, somehow extended even beyond the earth's gravitational field; for he says:
"Evidently on account of this law of gravitation they (Hindu) consider heaven too as having a globular shape". But nothing further on the subject can be gleaned from his work."

Nonetheless, Aryabhata and his successors much progressed compared to Aristotle and Ptolemy in other aspects of astronomy, such as rotating Earth. Indeed, the terrestrial attraction was used to answer the classical fly-off objection to it:

"Indian speculation on the subject
was refreshingly free of such mythological lumber. It is interesting to note that Aryabhata and his followers completely discarded the idea of concentric spheres. Nor did they feel any necessity for imagining an unmoved mover to
explain planetary movements... He took the bold step of
replacing it drastically by the theory of a moving earth and a stationary universe surrounding it. The proof of this is provided by a lost text of his conserved in Prthudakasvamin's commentary on the Brahmaghupta-siddhanta.
The text reads: "The celestial world is stationary, it is the earth which by its continuous rotation causes the daily rising and the setting of the planets as well as the stars".


[...] Al-Biruni also quoted another passage bearing on the problem from the same book: The followers of Aryabhata maintain that the earth is moving and heaven resting. People have tried to refute them by claiming that if such were the case, stones and trees would fall from the earth'. The answer of the Aryabhatiya school is given by al-Biruni in the following words: "That (viz. the earth leaving behind heavy objects) would not necessarily follow from their theory because... all heavy things are attracted towards the centre of the earth.""


Was Aryabhata close to a Heliocentric Model? How exactly did he explain the day night cycle?

So does that mean that by "Gurutva" (Massive body), Brahmagupta was referring to Earth?

@PrasoonJha Per Brahmagupta's quote, "heavy/massive bodies" are those attracted to the Earth, like rocks. According to Roy, Aryabhata started with something close to the Ptolemaic model, but allowing deferents and epicycles to be ovals, then switched to rotating Earth (relative to the fixed stars). He did not propose heliocentrism, although van der Waerden speculated that he was familiar with Aristarchus's and it influenced his epicycle configurations. The evidence for this is scant and historians are skeptical, see Swerdlow.
